# codeigniter global array for a model

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In my controller I want to declare a global variable which will always fetch all areas from my db

currently I'm passing `$data['dropdowns']`
in all methods in my class

```
{
$data['dropdowns']=loading some other model method
$this->load->view('commons/header',$data);  
}

{
  $data['dropdowns']=loading some other model metod
$this->load->view('commons/header',$data);  
}

{
  $data['dropdowns']=loading some other model metod
$this->load->view('commons/header',$data);  
}

{
   $data['dropdowns']=loading some other model metod
$this->load->view('commons/header',$data);  
}
```

the thing is I want to now send `$data['area']` to all the views without having to declare it again and again in each method

```
$data['area']= $this->area_model->get_all_locations();
```

Comment: Please use backticks (`code`) to make the code in your flow text easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add global variable , but as per my suggest to use global function to use any where to using to send parameter, so please check below my code.

Note : please load your model in application/config/autoload.php file

This is simple demo :
controller

```
{
 $data['dropdowns']=$this->your_model_name->get_records('table_name','select field like id, name');
 $this->load->view('commons/header',$data);  
}

{
 $data['dropdowns']=$this->your_model_name->get_records('table_name','select field like id, name,user_name');
 $this->load->view('commons/header',$data);  
}
```

Your model

```
function get_records($table_name,$field_name)
{
   $this->db->select("$field_name");
   $this->db->from("$table_name");
   $query=$this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

create a base_controller and placed in application/core

```
class base_controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public $area = array();
    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Controller constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->get_area();
    }
    public function get_area() {
        $this->load->model('area_model');
        $this->area= $this->area_model->get_all_locations();
    }
}
```

now $this->area is available in all controller which extends base_controller and all common functionality you can put here

```
class homepage extends base_controller{
    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Controller constructor
        parent::__construct();

    }
public function index()
    {
        $data = $this->area; // call this wherever u need
        $this->load->view('commons/header',$data);

    }

}
```

importantly $this->area; one can use directly inside view

Comment: i dint want to call it again and again  thing is there are 50 methods and other than pasting it in all methods  i want to directly pass to all methods

Comment: this is not method, it's a variable dude or u can use $this->area directly inside view too. no need to use in controller

Comment: @Kool-Mind You should follow the ucfirst rule latest versions of codeigniter as said here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world and http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html?highlight=core#extending-core-class

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper for your custom functions

Eg: `custom_helper.php` then load your custom helper in `autoload.php`

In `custom_helper.php`, create a function for getting area.

```
if (!function_exists('get_area')) {
    function get_area() {
        $CI = & get_instance(); 
        $area= $CI->area_model->get_all_locations();
        return $area;
    }
}
```

You can call `get_area()` in your views without declaring in controllers..

Comment: gonna give it a try